# Compute accuracy of each class?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have the following:
`test_labels=np.array([0,1,1,3,2])` and `preds=np.array([0,2,3,3,2])` -- the output should then be `output_fractions_correct=np.array([1.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5])`, i.e., a summery of the accuracy of each class. How can I compute the number(fraction) of correctly classified example for a class and do this for each class? I would like to give you an example of what I have tried but trust me that wouldn't help. Thanks.

I think I can get it to work with for loops but there must be some wizard way with Numpy.

To elaborate: The accuracy of a class(the value of the array elements) is given by the number of indicies for which `test_labels[i]=preds[i]` divided by the number of occurences of class i in `preds`. This is for example why class 3 has an accuracy of `2/1=0.5`. I am aware that in reality one would consider occurences in `test_labels` but that doesn't matter here :)

Comment: I think you are going to have to explicitly explain how to lists of five values `[0,1,1,3,2]` and  `[0,2,3,3,2]` relates to one line of four values `[1.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5]`. It's not clear (at least to me).

Comment: Okay, thanks for feedback. I will :)

Comment: @Mark Is this better?

Comment: Yeah, that's clearer. However `2/1=0.5`, seems backward `2 / 1 == 2`, but if you reverse the fraction you will have a problem that class `1` doesn't happen in your predicate, which leaves you dividing by zero.

Comment: Yes, typo. And yes, I would then assume that there at least is one occurence in `preds` of every class :)

Comment: You can get the counts of each item and divide:`np.bincount(test_labels) / np.bincount(preds)`. That should be fast, but I'm not certain if gives the results you want when there are more items in `test_labels` that `preds`.

Comment: @Mark But I would first have to count the number of correctly classified classes in the sense that `test_labels[i] = preds[i]`. Your comment doesn't seem to include that

Comment: @Mark So I guess the thing I need is how to compute an array such that each element `i` of this array holds the number of matches between `test_labels` and `preds` for a class `i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.bincount()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) with weights where the weights come from the test of `test_labels == preds`. This will yield a list of bools (which translate to 1 or 0 when used as weights). Taken together you get:

(I added some extra entries to make sure `1` is represented in the `preds` which you need for the division):

```
test_labels=np.array([0,1,1,3,2,1,1,1,2])
preds =     np.array([0,2,3,3,2,1,1,3,1]) 

np.bincount(preds, weights=test_labels==preds) / np.bincount(preds)
# array([1. , 0.66666667, 0.5, 0.33333333])
```

That should correspond to the following classes:

`0`: 1 correct out of 1: `1.0`
`1`: 2 correct out of 3: `0.66`
`2`: 1 correct out of 2: `0.5`
`3`: 1 correct out of 3: `0.33`

Comment: Much love! <3 Thank you.